# How to Automate login to a webpage using jsoup in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

I was trying to make an automatic login for my users to http://www.bvrit.edu.in using jsoup and the display the logged in web page for my users using a webview.I added the jsoup API,checked using inspect elements that the id of the usename field is txtId1 and password is txtPwd1 and replace data in post with the respective names.I also added the internet access permission to manifest but i am not able to display the webpage my code is as shown below,i think i am getting some basics wrong but had not been able to figure it out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bvritWebview);

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bvrit.edu.in/")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .timeout(12000)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Connection.Response loginFormFilled = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bvrit.edu.in/")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
            .followRedirects(true)
            .referrer("https://login.to/")
            .data("txtId1", "username")//check the form to find field name for user name
            .data("txtPwd1", "password")//check the form to find field name for user password
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();
    int statusCode = loginFormFilled.statusCode();
    Map<String, String> cookies = loginFormFilled.cookies();
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl("http://www.bvrit.edu.in");

}
```

}

header section of the networking after logigng in-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing few parameters in your `POST` request. Load the page in your browser, press F12 to launch the developer tools and look at the `POST` request. You will see something like this -
[image: POST request]

You must send all these parameters to the server, not just those you do send now.
The first 3 parameters are unique to each session, and you can get them form the first `GET` request, something like this (the CSS selector may be different, I didn't try it on your URL):

```
Document doc = loginForm.parse();
Element e = doc.select("input[id=__VIEWSTATE]").first();
String viewState = e.attr("value");
```

Comment: thanks for your help i had added a pic after getting the loging to the website soo you wnat me to add like .data("__VIEWSTATE" ,"data of viewstate") and same for "viewstategenerator and "Evenyvalidation"..right..

Comment: is the rest of my code all correct..please bear with me as i am just a beginner..

Comment: You must add all the parameters. The first 3 will change in each session: __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION and you have to extract them from the first `GET` request as I showed to you in my answer. The rest of the parameters have fixed values, like the ones in the picture that you have added to your question. Rest of the code looks OK to me.